# Canvas drawImage returns error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this piece of code (The sCtx is a canvas context and the button is in a tight draw loop):

```
function Button(src, onClick)
{
   this.loaded = false;
   this.image = new Image();
   this.image.src = src;

   this.onClick = onClick;
}

Button.prototype.draw = function()
{
   if(!this.image.complete)
      return;

   var theImg = this.image;

   console.log(theImg);
   sCtx.drawImage(theImg);
}
```

When I run the code (in Chrome) I get this output:

> <img src=​"img/​btnStart.png">
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I have looked at many examples and it seems like this should work.

Comment: I am having the same problem . despite of adding the x,y coordinates the error is still there. What should I do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need x/y coordinates in order to tell the canvas context where to draw:

```
sCtx.drawImage(theImg,0,0);
```